# Binding a multi dimentional javascript array as method parameter in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

hi i am looking for a way to bind this data :

```
columns[0][data]:0
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:1
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:2
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:3
columns[3][name]:
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
columns[4][data]:4
columns[4][name]:
columns[4][searchable]:true
columns[4][orderable]:true
columns[4][search][value]:
columns[4][search][regex]:false
columns[5][data]:5
columns[5][name]:
columns[5][searchable]:true
columns[5][orderable]:true
columns[5][search][value]:
columns[5][search][regex]:false
columns[6][data]:6
columns[6][name]:
columns[6][searchable]:true
columns[6][orderable]:true
columns[6][search][value]:
columns[6][search][regex]:false
columns[7][data]:7
columns[7][name]:
columns[7][searchable]:true
columns[7][orderable]:true
columns[7][search][value]:
columns[7][search][regex]:false
columns[8][data]:8
columns[8][name]:
columns[8][searchable]:true
columns[8][orderable]:false
columns[8][search][value]:
columns[8][search][regex]:false
```

to my method so far i tried an object array but it didn't work here is my method definition:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> DriveDataTable(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
```

and jQueryDataTableParamModel class :

```
public class jQueryDataTableParamModel
{
    //Paging first record indicator. This is the start point in the current data set (0 index based - i.e. 0 is the first record).
    public int start { get; set; }
    // global search keyword
    public string search { get; set; }
    // Number of records that should be shown in table
    public int length { get; set; }
    //represent the index of column which is to ordered 
    public int orderByCol { get; set; }
    //order direction (asc or desc)
    public string orderDirection { get; set; }

    public object[] columns { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the data to the controller or from the controller to the grid? How are you passing it, AJAX? If you are passing it to the controller then the param is of wrong type. Pls give more details and I will try and help

Comment: i am using jquery-datable and as you guess i am posting the given multidimentional array via AJAX. so why you think the param is in wrong type it already works for other parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `myArr` is your javascript multidimensional array you can npass it to c# in this way

```
JSON.stringify(myArr)
```

then in c# class you can change the property in

```
public object columns { get; set; }
```

but I think that also

`public string columns { get; set; }` should work

then server side you could deserialize it in some way

Usually I send serialized objects over javascript and when they come back in a string format to my C# methods I deserialize them in this way

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult MyMethod(string model)
 {
     //model in this case is what JSON.stringify(myArr) sends
     var jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
     jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
     var deserializedModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyComplexType>(model, jsSettings);
     //now deserializedModel is of type MyComplexType
     return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Somefile.cshtml", deserializedModel);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your a great approach to problem. i tried it and it worked but i am realy wondering if there is a more compact solution to problem...

Comment: I've done some update just to show how you can use my code in a working example, I always use this solution, hope it can help you.

Comment: thank you :) i moved on before your update and did almost same think as shown in your update (by the way converting complex javascript array to string and pass it to server is really good idea :)  ).

Answer (score 1):

Additional Information.

**Here Is classes**

```
public class JQDTParams
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }

        public int start { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }


        public JQDTColumnSearch  /*Dictionary<string, string>*/ search { get; set; }
        public List<JQDTColumnOrder/*Dictionary<string, string>*/> order { get; set; }
        public List<JQDTColumn/*Dictionary<string, string>*/> columns { get; set; }

    }


    public enum JQDTColumnOrderDirection
    {
        asc, desc
    }

    public class JQDTColumnOrder
    {
        public int column { get; set; }
        public JQDTColumnOrderDirection dir { get; set; }
    }
    public class JQDTColumnSearch
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string regex { get; set; }
    }

    public class JQDTColumn
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Boolean searchable { get; set; }
        public Boolean orderable { get; set; }
        public JQDTColumnSearch search { get; set; }
    }
```

**And Usage**

> ***HTML***

```
<div>

    <table id="aractipiListesi" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="filter-input">
                <th>PK</th>
                <th>Markası</th>
                <th>Modeli</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>PK</th>
                <th>Markası</th>
                <th>Modeli</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#aractipiListesi').DataTable({
              "processing": true,
              "serverSide": true,
              "filter": true,
              "pageLength": 8,
              "columns": [
                  {
                      "name": "ID",
                      "orderable": false
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "MARKAADI",
                      "orderable": true
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "TIPADI",
                      "orderable": true
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "SEC",
                      "orderable": false
                  }
              ],
              "ajax":
                  {
                      url: "@Url.Action("AracTipiAra", "Common", new { area = "" })",
                      type: "post"
                  },
              "columnDefs":
                  [
                      {
                          "render": function (data, type, row) { return AracTipiListesiTableDropDownToggle(data, type, row); },
                          "targets": [3]
                      },
                      {
                          "visible": false,
                          "targets": [0]
                      }
                  ],

              "language": DTConstants.Language


          });

          var aractipi_filtrelenecekBasliklar = ['Markası', 'Modeli'];
          // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
          $('#aractipiListesi thead .filter-input th').each(function () {
              var title = $(this).text();
              if (title != '' && $.inArray(title, aractipi_filtrelenecekBasliklar) >= 0) {
                  $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + ' Ara" />');
              }
          });

          // DataTable
          var table = $('#aractipiListesi').DataTable();

          // Apply the search
          table.columns().every(function () {
              var that = this;

              $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                  if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                      that.search(this.value).draw();
                  }
              });
          });
        });
    </script>


</div>
```

---

> Controller

---

```
 public JsonResult AracTipiAra(JQDTParams param)
        {
            using (var db = new MBOSSEntities())
            {
                var q = from x in db.VW_ARACMARKATIPI select x;
                var nonfilteredcount = q.Count();
                //filter 
                //-------------------------------------------------------------------
                foreach (var item in param.columns)
                {
                    var filterText = item.search.value;
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
                    {
                        filterText = filterText.ToLower();
                        switch (item.name)
                        {
                            case "MARKAADI":
                                q = q.Where(
                       x =>
                           x.MARKAADI.ToLower().Contains(filterText)

                   );
                                break;
                            case "TIPADI":
                                q = q.Where(
                       x =>
                           x.TIPADI.ToLower().Contains(filterText)

                   );
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //order
                //-------------------------------------------------------------------
                foreach (var item in param.order)
                {
                    string orderingFunction = "MARKAADI";
                    switch (item.column)
                    {
                        case 1: orderingFunction = "MARKAADI";
                            break;

                        case 2: orderingFunction = "TIPADI";
                            break;

                    }

                    q = OrderClass.OrderBy<VW_ARACMARKATIPI>(q, orderingFunction, item.dir.GetStringValue());
                }

                //result
                //-------------------------------------------------------------------
                var filteredCount = q.Count();
                q = q.Skip(param.start).Take(param.length);
                var data = q.ToList()
                    .Select(r => new[] {
                        r.ARACMARKAPK.ToString(),
                        r.MARKAADI,
                        r.TIPADI,
                    }

                    );
                return Json(new
                {
                    draw = param.draw,
                    recordsTotal = nonfilteredcount,
                    recordsFiltered = filteredCount,
                    data = data
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }

        }
```